# vb check for specific file type in dir and perform code

Tags: vb.net, file-type

I'm trying to make a program that checks for specific file type in a directory, then executes a code if there are any files of that type found.

I'm assuming something like this:

```
For Each foundFile As String In
  My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)

  (If any found files are, for example, "txt" files, then display their content.)
Next
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any specific questions or you just want someone to code it for you?

Comment: Don't really have any specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) with a parameter for the extension-filter:

```
Dim directoryPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
Dim allTxtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, ".txt") 
For each file As String In allTxtFiles
    Console.WriteLine(file)
Next
```

The difference between both methods is that the first returns a `String()`, so loads all into memory immediately whereas the second returns a "query". If you want to use LINQ it's better to use `EnumerateFiles`, f.e. if you want to take the first 10 files:

```
Dim firstTenFiles As List(Of String) = allTxtFiles.Take(10).ToList()
```

Comment: thanks alot! it really helped! From what i understand, `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` can send a query for the first x amount of txt files in the dir?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)
For Each fi In di.GetFiles("*.txt")
    Dim content As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fi.FullName)
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name)
Next
```